# PHP Get value from array within array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sorry if this is a basic question but I'm just having trouble getting a value from an array within an array.  Here is my code:

```
$data = Array (
    [message-count] => 1
    [messages] => Array (
         [0] => Array (
               [to] => 19998887777
               [message-price] => 0.00550000
               [status] => 0
               [message-id] => 0300000021B6B103
               [remaining-balance] => 18.59500000
               [network] => 31000
          )
     )
);
```

Then, for example, if I wanted to retrieve the message-id, I'm trying:

```
$messageID = $data['message-count']['messages']['message-id'];
```

That doesn't return anything so I know I'm missing something simple.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just miss the 0

```
$data["messages"][0]["message-id"]
```

Answer (score 3):

`message-count` appears to be `1`.  `messages` is an array of arrays, and that array contains `message-id`.  To get the first message id, you would use

```
$data["messages"][0]["message-id"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Note how I formatted your code snippet above. You forgot the `[0]` portion, so your assignment would be

```
$messageID = $data['messages'][0]['message-id'];
                              ^^^---forgot this
```

The `['message-count']` is not necessary, because it's not part of the "tree" branch you're going down.